# How to mount a USB drive

Tags: mount, usb-drive

I'm a newbie to Ubuntu. I just plugged in a 30 GB USB mini hard drive, but it doesn't seem to be detected.  Unfortunately the page in the [manual](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB) seems to be missing.  I'm sure this is easy, but without the help page I've no idea how to start.

Right this is the output from `dmesg`:

```
[  519.736244] usb 3-1.2: Device not responding to setup address.
[  519.940195] usb 3-1.2: Device not responding to setup address.
[  520.144045] usb 3-1.2: device not accepting address 10, error -71
[  520.216055] usb 3-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[  520.216245] usb 3-1.2: Device not responding to setup address.
[  520.420216] usb 3-1.2: Device not responding to setup address.
[  520.624057] usb 3-1.2: device not accepting address 11, error -71
[  520.624202] usb 3-1-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
[  689.213242] systemd-hostnamed[2479]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
[ 2832.970074] systemd-hostnamed[2719]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
```

Doesn't look good to my untrained eye.

And this is from `lsblk`:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
fd0      2:0    1     4K  0 disk
sda      8:0    0  76.3G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0  72.3G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0     4G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   0 465.8G  0 part /media/john/B84433E54433A4D2
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Ubuntu is on the 80GB, the 465 is a Windows partition.

Comment: Generally, you shouldn't need to do anything, other then plug it in. It should be visible and clickable in the file manager's left side panel. If that doesn't happen, please add the output of `dmesg | tail` to the question.

Comment: He said that's not working ^

Comment: I said that?  It's in the unedited question...

Comment: From the `dmesg` output, you can see, that the kernel is not happy with your USB drive and doesn't assign a block device (that would appear in the output of `lsblk`). What's the output of `lsusb`? Maybe it's listed there with a device ID and all.

Comment: As David mentioned, the kernel isn't liking something about the USB drive. Hate to ask the obvious, but have you tried different USB ports? Do other USB drives work?

Comment: Good point, Eric. Does the USB drive work with other machines or operating systems?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the device connected via an USB-hub (or even an extra cable), remove it from there...
and connect it to an USB connector in your computer (no extras between!).